# Had Darth Sidious foreseen that Jar Jar Binks would provide assistance to Qui-Gon, Obi-Wan, and Queen Amidala on the planet Naboo?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, the-phantom-menace, jar-jar-binks

Using the Force, Darth Sidious could often foresee many things or events that would take place in the future. In *Return of the Jedi*, he had foreseen Luke Skywalker coming to see Darth Vader to see if he could turn him back to the Light Side.

In regards to *Star Wars: Episode I: The Phantom Menace*, had Darth Sidious foreseen that Jar Jar Binks would provide assistance to Qui-Gon, Obi-Wan, and Queen Amidala on the planet Naboo?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Jar Jar is one of the little people. If it wasn't him, it would have been someone else, or no-one.

Comment: Why wouldn't he have?  If the whole Jar Jar arc is aborted then Anakin doesn't get found.  Perhaps the _entire point_ of the invasion of Naboo was to get Anakin noticed and picked up?

Comment: @DavidW isn't that statement a bit of a stretch? You can't proof Anakin wouldn't be found if Jar Jar wasn't around. Surely Qui-Gon would have become alerted of the presence of the Force in him at some point or would have been guided to him in another way. Qui-Gon says so himself later on over the comlink to Obi-Wan that it was no coincidence.

Comment: @Mixxiphoid My point is only that there's no reason to suppose that Sidious _didn't_ foresee all this.  Maybe this is the only way that Anakin ends up apprenticed to Obi-Wan, or maybe this way he gets separated from his mom in a way that leaves him wracked with guilt when she dies.  We have _no idea_ what Sidious has foreseen, and how much of what happens is within acceptable parameters for his ultimate goal.

Comment: @DavidW, I tend to agree with you that Darth Sidious had most likely foreseen all the things that would take place on Naboo and Tatooine. If this is so, then he must have foreseen that Darth Maul would be killed on Naboo. Darth Maul then was just a means to an end in order for him to setup events that would one day lead Anakin to the Dark Side.

Comment: @user57467  Maul was not exactly killed on Naboo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, for the most part, ambiguous how much Sidious was able to foresee.

I would make the case that he didn't predict the Jedi coming to Naboo at all, much less what they would do once they arrived.

He at least claims that the Jedi are putting a wrinkle in his plot that requires the plan to change, suggesting that he didn't know with certainty that they would get involved.

> This turn of events is unfortunate. We must accelerate our plans.

Of course, he could be pretending to have not known but I would argue this is not the case. He tells the Trade Federation to

> Kill them immediately.

Notably, the Trade Federation initially underestimate the Jedi and use an ineffective gas attack on them. Since Sidious ends up wanting the Jedi killed, he likely would have warned and prepared the Trade Federation far in advance, if he predicted the Jedi presence long before.

Of course, it could be argued that he knew the Jedi would come, and knew that the Trade Federation would fail to kill them, but told the Trade Federation to try anyway, as part of his scheme. However, this would require a level of extreme clarity in telling the future and the Force is generally more murky for something this complicated.

Additionally, his plot requires Naboo to be as threatened as possible, both to make Valorum look bad and to gain sympathy for himself. The Jedi are the most likely party in the galaxy to resolve things, so he would probably want them dead if they tried to intervene. Therefore, he would likely better prepare the Trade Federation if he predicted the Jedi getting involved in advance.